# O365 Sharepoint - Will renaming a top level folder that contains other shared items/folder break the links?

Tags: office-365

Example:
we have an SP Library called;
'Our Shared folder' which contains Files + Other  folders that have shared links to them (set to not expire)
If we rename 'Our Shared Library' to something else,  will this break the links?

Or renaming any folder name that contains a shared file or folder break the shared link?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No. You can change the library title all day long. It won't make any difference.

Your shared links will be completely fine. If you inspect any shared link, you will discover that they don't contain the exact link to a file or folder. These shared links also don't include Library names. Instead, sharing links contain a unique ID that remains intact despite the changes of the Library Title of folder names.